# Add label text to radio buttons in Wordpress site using Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, forms, accessibility, contact-form-7

I'm trying to improve my website by making it more accessible and compliant with WCAG 2.0 (Level AA) guidelines. It's a Wordpress site that uses Contact Form 7 to create forms. By default, Contact Form 7 doesn't add a `label` to its `input` elements. It's easy enough to manually add a `label` complete with a `for` attribute to `input` of type "text":

```
<label for="address">Street Address*</label><br />
[text* Address1 id:address]
```

However, I'm having trouble doing this for radio buttons. I know that there's an option to "use_label_element" when generating a radio button tag with Contact Form 7, however this just generates an empty `label` tag -- it doesn't include the `for` attribute. Here's the code that I've tried:

```
[radio RelativesWork use_label_element "Yes" "No"]
```

That shortcode generates the following HTML. Note that the ID I added with the shortcode is put on the wrapper `span`, and that the each `label` does not contain the `for` attribute.

```html
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap RelativesWork">
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio" id="relatives">
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="RelativesWork" value="Yes" />&nbsp;
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Yes</span>
      </label>
    </span>
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item last">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="RelativesWork" value="No" />&nbsp;
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">No</span>
      </label>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

I learned that there's a supplemental plugin called "Contact Form 7: Accessible Defaults", so I installed and tried that. However, as far as I can tell, that doesn't address radio buttons at all.

Can anyone help me figure out how to add a `label` that contains the `for` attribute to each radio button I create with Contact Form 7.

Thanks!

Jenn

Comment: Can you edit your question and share your CF7 code for this set of radios?

Comment: @mevius, Thanks for taking the time to try to help. I've edited my question to include the code.

Comment: Is there a reason you need the `for` attribute? When a `label` wraps an `input`, it still associates the caption with a control element (as proven by the snippet in your question).

Comment: Because when I run my site thru AChecker I get the following error:  "input element, type of "radio", has no text in label." (More info here: http://achecker.ca/checker/suggestion.php?id=204)

Comment: According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element), what you have is completely valid: *"The label element represents a caption in a user interface. The caption can be associated with a specific form control, known as the label element's labeled control, either using the for attribute, or by putting the form control inside the label element itself."*

Comment: Hmmm... perhaps this is more of an error with AChecker then. Thanks. I've upvoted your comment.

Comment: Hello @jennEDVT did you get your answer? I have faced the same issue. In fact, my Contact form is in a modal which doesn't support normal page ready jquery codes. Please mention if you got any solution.

Comment: Your labels are not empty, they contain texts inside them: "Yes" and "No" (they are wrapped by a span tag, however). It seems that Contact Form 7 uses the "value" information as the label.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with CF7 plugin as is, as it has several shortcomings such as this when it comes to customising the front-end form.

To achieve this, there are 2 options, *hack* the form using javascript once it is loaded to add an `id` attribute to the input field and a `for` attribute to the label element.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42144642/3596672) to see how it is done,

```
<label> My radio button
       [radio amount id:amount class:amount-select default:1 "50" "100" "200" "500" "Other"]</label>
    [submit]
    <script>
       (function( $ ) {
         $(document).ready( function(){
           $('form.wpcf7-form input').each(function(){
             var span = $(this).parent('span');
             if(span){
               var idAttr = span.attr('id');
               $(this).attr('id',idAttr);
               span.attr('id','');
             }
             //or you could also do this which is even less maintenance
             var name = $(this).attr('name');
             var type = $(this).attr('type');
             switch(type){
               case 'radio':
               case 'checkbox':
                 name += '-'+$(this).attr('value');
             }
             $(this).attr('id',name);
           });
         });
       })( jQuery );
    </script>
```

Or you can use version 4.11 of the [Smart Grid-layout extension for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) plugin (currently v4.10 is available, but the next version will be out in a week, a beta version can be downloaded from the [repo](https://github.com/aurovrata/cf7-grid-layout)) which will introduce a dynamic_checkbox field that is properly formatted, although if you are looking for simple yes/no radio fields, then the first solution is simpler.