# How to add ID and Class attribute on Input Type in Contact Form 7

Tags: contact-form-7

I want to add Id and Class attribute on specific input type in our contact form 7.

When I am adding with below example, it apply Id and Class on SPAN tag just above the input Type

```
[radio amount id:amount class:amount-select default:1 "50" "100" "200" "500" "Other"]
```

Here is the screenshot of source which is generated from above code:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to do so through the contact form 7 plugin.  You'll need to add some custom javascript to do so, for example for your specific `[radio]` tag you would do something like this inside the cf7 edit page,

```
    <label> My radio button
       [radio amount id:amount class:amount-select default:1 "50" "100" "200" "500" "Other"]</label>
    [submit]
    <script>
       (function( $ ) {
         $(document).ready( function(){
           $('form.wpcf7-form input').each(function(){
             var span = $(this).parent('span');
             if(span){
               var idAttr = span.attr('id');
               $(this).attr('id',idAttr);
               span.attr('id','');
             }
             //or you could also do this which is even less maintenance
             var name = $(this).attr('name');
             var type = $(this).attr('type');
             switch(type){
               case 'radio':
               case 'checkbox':
                 name += '-'+$(this).attr('value');
             }
             $(this).attr('id',name);
           });
         });
       })( jQuery );
    </script>
```

this would move all the span ids to the input elements when the page loads, you could use the same logic to move non-wpcf7 classes to the input element too.

[Edit] I added an additional method which needs less maintenance, although keep in mind that for radio/checkbox elements you'll need to append the value to the id to make it unique.

Comment: Yes, I have added same with custom javascript. 

Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SASS style rules why not extend the Contact form 7 classes to your own classes? With this approach there is need to write JavaScript.

See my example below:

```
.wpcf7-form label {
    @extend .control-group__label;
}

.wpcf7-form-control {
  @extend .control-group__control;
}

.wpcf7-submit {
  @extend .btn;
  @extend .btn-submit;
}
```